# DSN: Service unavailable sendmail linux

Tags: linux, email, smtp, sendmail

I just installed `sendmail` on my linux os.

I can't seem to receive emails, this is what I see in logs:

```
    Aug 10 14:12:10 localhost sendmail[13316]: v7A9CAPC013316: from=root, size=238, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201708100912.v7A9CAPC013316@localhost.test>, relay=root@localhost
Aug 10 14:12:10 localhost sendmail[13317]: v7A9CAwD013317: from=<root@localhost.test>, size=484, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201708100912.v7A9CAPC013316@localhost.test>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Aug 10 14:12:10 localhost sendmail[13316]: v7A9CAPC013316: to=sandeelo.danyal@gmail.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30238, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v7A9CAwD013317 Message accepted for delivery)
Aug 10 14:12:12 localhost sendmail[13319]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Aug 10 14:12:13 localhost sendmail[13319]: v7A9CAwD013317: to=<sandeelo.danyal@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<root@localhost.test> (0/0), delay=00:00:03, xdelay=00:00:03, mailer=esmtp, pri=120484, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.133.26], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Aug 10 14:12:13 localhost sendmail[13319]: v7A9CAwD013317: v7A9CDwD013319: DSN: Service unavailable
Aug 10 14:12:13 localhost sendmail[13319]: v7A9CDwD013319: to=<root@localhost.test>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31714, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

Comment: You question seem to be fit for stackoverflow site.  Your sendmail seems to be unable to deliver/pass messages to gmail.com.  Could you include bounce email received by the sender?

Answer (score 13):

1. Fix sender domain name (`from=<root@localhost.test>` => `localhost.test`)
   Change name (FQDN) of the host to name with valid `MX`/`A` records
2. As root use the script below to get full transcript of SMTP session.
   It should give you a better idea what is disliked by gmail.

test script (for use by `root`):

```
#!/bin/sh
TO=somebody@gmail.com

# -i  - do not treat special lines starting with "."
# -v  - use verbose mode (provide SMTP session transcript)
# -Am - use sendmail.cf (do not send via localhost:25) - requires root privileges
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -v -Am -- $TO <<END
Subject: Delivery test
To: $TO

Delivery test.
END
```

Comment: In my case I discovered a typo in my username, very helpful script.

Comment: After configuration, the above script send an email but this one not. `echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v somebody@gmaill.com`    
I end up getting `STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message.`      
Any idea?

Comment: The reason is probably that I am overwriting mian@localhost.localdomain in sendmail with a proper email, which is taking effect in your script but not in my script.

Comment: This one work `echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -i -v -Am mianasbat@gmail.com`. Something fishy in -i and -Am.

Comment: After I used AnFi's script, I was able to see that my "DSN: Service unavailable" was actually "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted." in the detail log. My solution was to allow less secure apps in my gmail account settings.  I was using smtp.gmail.com via relay.  Thank you very much for the script.